# SSL in EC2 without ELB

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am running a Spring Boot application in EC2. I want to make the API calls as HTTPS instead of HTTP. 
This is what I did: 
Brought a domain in godaddy and configured it in Route 53. 
Created a cert from AWS certificate manager. 
Created a Load Balancer and added the cert. 
In route 53 directed my traffic to ELB.

Above things are working fine now. I have only one instance. Use of ELB is only for SSL. But I want to get rid of ELB as it is costing me more

Is there any other way I can make the API calls as HTTPS for spring boot application running on ec2 without ELB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELB can be quite expensive, and most of all useless if you have only one instance.

Try to put CloudFront in....well...front of your instance. You get the benefit of managing AWS certificates in the same way you are doing with the LB, and also you can take advantage of caching and edge locations.

You can also redirect Route53 to CloudFront, just add a CNAME to your hosted zone that reference the cloud front DNS.